# I'm using GPU-enabled Milvus. But why it seems to me searching is sometimes slower than CPU-only Milvus?

Tags: search, gpu, config, cpu, milvus

I'm using GPU-enabled Milvus. But why it seems to me searching is sometimes slower than CPU-only Milvus? Are there any specific settings specifically for GPU-enabled Milvus?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more!

Comment: You can take a look at this : https://milvus.io/docs/v0.10.3/performance_faq.md#Why-GPU-enabled-query-is-sometimes-slower-than-CPU-only-query

Answer (score 0):

how about your dataset counts?

GPU performance better than CPU usually happens to large dataset number.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the number of queries (nq). Before searching, Milvus needs to load the dataset into its gpu and this take significant amount of time. As nq increases to a certain value that faster search time compensates load time, gpu becomes faster than cpu.

Answer (score 0):

**Extract milvus gpu executable file from docker**

Download Milvus GPU

```
wget https://ymu.dl.osdn.jp/datasets/75612/milvus-gpu-1.1.0.tar
or
wget https://ymu.dl.osdn.jp/datasets/75612/milvus-gpu-1.1.1.tar
```

```
tar -xzvf milvus-gpu-1.1.0.tar
or
tar -xzvf milvus-gpu-1.1.1.tar
```

Install and Start Milvus GPU

```
apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-server
wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/212189159/libmysqlclient18_5.6.25-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/212189147/libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.25-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.25-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb libmysqlclient18_5.6.25-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
apt-get install libopenblas-dev
chmod +x /var/lib/milvus/bin/milvus_server
./var/lib/milvus/bin/milvus_server -c ./var/lib/milvus/conf/server_config.yaml
```

### Hello Milvus

```
pip install pymilvus==1.1.0
pip install grpcio==1.37.0
pip install grpcio-tools==1.37.0
```

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/milvus-io/pymilvus/v1.1.0/examples/example.py
or
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/milvus-io/pymilvus/v1.1.1/examples/example.py
```

```
python example.py
```

中文参考：[矩池云上安装及使用Milvus教程](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_48344945/article/details/119000281)